# Python Selenium Football Odds Webscraping

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape odds from https://en.stoiximan.gr/live. While my code is working, I get an error for having uneven lists in my final `dataframe`. Unfortunately, `stoiximan` seems to place 3-way odds together with over/under odds and suspended/locked matches (as in the picture).

[image: stoiximan odds]

What I am trying to do is to delete both home and away teams from their respective lists if their odds are over/under or locked. Any suggestions?

Here 's my code so far:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
import time
import openpyxl
import os

#launch chrome and keep window open
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)

#visit en.stoiximan.gr and maximize window
driver.get("https://en.stoiximan.gr/live/")
driver.maximize_window()

#close modal window
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((
        By.XPATH, "//button[@class='sb-modal__close__btn uk-modal-close-default uk-icon uk- 
        close']"
    ))).click()
except:
    pass

#accept cookies
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((
    By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"
    ))).click()

#Initialize storage for stoiximan
stoiximan_home_teams_list = []
stoiximan_away_teams_list = []
stoiximan_home_odds_list = []
stoiximan_draw_odds_list = []
stoiximan_away_odds_list = []

#grab all home/away teams and explicit odds
try:
    stoiximan_home_teams = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, 
        "//div[@class='live-events-event-row__container live-event live-events-event- 
        row__container--row']/div[1]/a/div[1]/div[1]/span"))
        )

    stoiximan_away_teams = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, 
        "//div[@class='live-events-event-row__container live-event live-events-event-row__container--row']/div[1]/a/div[1]/div[2]/span"))
        )

    stoiximan_home_odds = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, 
        "//div[@class='live-events-event-row__container live-event live-events-event-row__container--row']/div[2]/div/button[1]/span[2]"))
        )

stoiximan_draw_odds = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, 
        "//div[@class='live-events-event-row__container live-event live-events-event-row__container--row']/div[2]/div/button[2]/span[2]"))
        )

stoiximan_away_odds = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((
        By.XPATH, 
        "//div[@class='live-events-event-row__container live-event live-events-event-row__container--row']/div[2]/div/button[3]/span[2]"))
        )

except:
   driver.quit()

#loop each home team and append the lists
for stoiximan_home_team in stoiximan_home_teams:
    stoiximan_home_teams_list.append(stoiximan_home_team.get_attribute('innerText'))

for stoiximan_away_team in stoiximan_away_teams:
    stoiximan_away_teams_list.append(stoiximan_away_team.get_attribute('innerText'))

for stoiximan_home_odd in stoiximan_home_odds:
    stoiximan_home_odds_list.append(stoiximan_home_odd.text)

for stoiximan_draw_odd in stoiximan_draw_odds:
    stoiximan_draw_odds_list.append(stoiximan_draw_odd.text)

for stoiximan_away_odd in stoiximan_away_odds:
    stoiximan_away_odds_list.append(stoiximan_away_odd.text)

print(stoiximan_home_teams_list)
print(len(stoiximan_home_teams_list))
print(stoiximan_away_teams_list)
print(len(stoiximan_away_teams_list))
print(stoiximan_home_odds_list)
print(len(stoiximan_home_odds_list))
print(stoiximan_draw_odds_list)
print(len(stoiximan_draw_odds_list))
print(stoiximan_away_odds_list)
print(len(stoiximan_away_odds_list))

#make str to float in odds lists
stoiximan_home_odds_list_float = [float(i) for i in stoiximan_home_odds_list]
stoiximan_draw_odds_list_float = [float(j) for j in stoiximan_draw_odds_list]
stoiximan_away_odds_list_float = [float(k) for k in stoiximan_away_odds_list]

#create dictionary for data
stoiximan_dict = {'Stoiximan Home Team': stoiximan_home_teams_list, 
                  'Stoiximan Away Team': stoiximan_away_teams_list, 
                  'Stoiximan Home Odd': stoiximan_home_odds_list_float, 
                  'Stoiximan Draw Odd': stoiximan_draw_odds_list_float, 
                  'Stoiximan Away Odd': stoiximan_away_odds_list_float
                 }

#create dataframe for data
df4 = pd.DataFrame(stoiximan_dict)

print(df4)

#write to excel file and open it
df4.to_excel(r'C:\Users\sweet_000\Desktop\data.xlsx', sheet_name="stoiximan", index=False)
os.system('start EXCEL.EXE "C:\\Users\\sweet_000\\Desktop\\data.xlsx"')

driver.quit()
```

Comment: Stoiximan.gr can only be accessed from Greece, in compliance with local regulations.

Comment: I'm sorry, hadn't 't noticed that. However, theoretically speaking, how would you approach this task?

Comment: @GeorgeGiannoulis, actually no need to use selenium here. I’m not at my laptop at the moment, but I’ll code up the solution for you for this later today.